# React.semantic ui's Icones are not loading with webpack middle ware

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to build a react application using React Semantic. 
I am using webpack-dev-server, webpack-hot-middleware and webpack-dev-middleware to automating the tasks.

I installed react semantic ui through npm.

```
npm install --save semantic-ui-css semantic-ui-react
```

however, webpack seems to not loading `./node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/assets/fonts/` icons and it is not accessabile for the html page. 
there is no errors in console, it just does not show the icon.

If I do not import semantic-ui-css in react app and includ in with CDN, it works fine.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import { Container, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
    return (
        <Container fluid>
            <h1 id='test'>ReactJs</h1>
            <hr/>
            <Icon name='search' />
        </Container>

    )
    }

}
export default App;
```

webpack.config.dev.js

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        path.join(__dirname, '/client/index.js')

    ],
    output:{
        path: '/',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin,
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),

        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],

    module:{
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
                loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader','sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,                
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
            },

            {
                 test: /\.svg$/,
                  loader: 'svg-loader' 
            },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|png)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }

        ]
    },
    resolve:{
        extensions: ['.js']
    }
}
```

Is there any loader or package to include icons from semantic ui package?

Answer (score 4):

I am also using SUI-React with webpack. I was having a similar problem, however for me the icon files were 'packed' by webpack, but weren't being loaded correctly. Are you sure that webpack isn't finding them at all?

I eventually found that the source of my issue was the webpack configuration: my output path was a `dist` subdirectory, from which the `index.html` loaded `bundle.js`. This meant that webpack (and `file-loader`) made the urls relative to that directory. Once I changed my output path to the parent directory, and changed the output file to be `dist/bundle.js`, everything worked as expected.

My `webpack.config.js` specifies the entrypoint as yours does (although only one entrypoint, I'm not using `webpack-hot-middleware`), and my loaders are:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?/,
    include: SRC_DIR,
    loader: 'babel'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader'
  }
]
```

I'm loading the css using

```
require("!style-loader!css-loader!semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css")
```

in the index file rather than using webpack loaders, however I think that should be equivalent to what you're doing.

Maybe your `.css` loader rule shouldn't include the `sass-loader`?

Also, the loader configuration option `use` seems to have been added in webpack v2, so if you're using webpack v1, that should be `loaders` as you have for the other rules.

Hope you can figure it out!